# Antd Design nested Table, How to pass whether row selected or not selected

Tags: reactjs, datatable, antd, react-table, nested-table

I am using nested tables, in ant design. If I select a row in the top-level table, It should select all the values in nested tables for that row. If I deselect any one of the rows in the nested table it should deselect the row in the top-level table.

I am trying to use the state to control but could not be able to manage all the cases

this is code https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-tables-antd-4-21-7-forked-9u713r?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

try to add `checkStrictly: false` to rowSelection object

```
 const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys,
    checkStrictly: false
  };
```